# Xpath wildcard search

Tags: xml, xpath, wildcard

I want to search within all nodes and all attributes for a specific text using xpath query.

Example:

```
<Employee>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Info FirstName="Search" LastName="Smith">
    <Address City="Search"/>
  </Info>
</Employee>
```

I am currently using the below xpath query:

```
var nodes = xmlConfig.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@*,'Search')]");
```

Xpath query should return Info node and Address node. However, it only returns one node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're using XPath 1.0, your XPath should have returned `Info` node and `Address` node as you expect. See online demo for that in the following link (click on 'test' button to execute the XPath) :

```
//*[contains(@*,'Search')]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester xpath 1.0 demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/808799ba4ff364f68db8650e5f7cc748)</kbd>**

In XPath 2.0, the above will throw exception *passing sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of `contains()`*, and that happen because one element may have more than one attribute. For XPath 2.0 compatible expression, you can do this way instead :

```
//*[@*[contains(.,'Search')]]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester xpath 2.0 demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/00c694006b85e32fffaa64467899b337)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<Info FirstName="Search" LastName="Smith">
    <Address City="Search"/>
  </Info>

<Address City="Search"/>
```