# Selenium Java not finding elements and/or can't click

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, xpath, webdriver

i hope you'll find a solution for my problem.

The page I try to test (I'll have an ARender deployed in my company and I need to test it) : http://arender.fr/ARender/

The xpath I use to click on next page (given by FireBug, I tried to use anothers but does the same thing):
`//*[@id='id_#_0.7290579307692522']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/img`

I tried many things and I really don't find the solution, I already tried to make a Javascript executor click it...

Java code :

```
package firstPackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import firstPackage.Props;
import firstPackage.methods;
import firstPackage.PropTech;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TestSelenium {

  private  WebDriver driver;
  protected static InternetExplorerDriverService service;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public  void setUp() 
    {   
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("launching IE browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", PropTech.driverPath+"IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    
    }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception 
  {
      driver.navigate().to("arender.fr" + "/ARender/");
      Thread.sleep(15000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Next page']/img")).click();
  }

  @After
    public  void tearDown() 
    {
        if(driver!=null) 
        {
            System.out.println("Closing IE browser");
            driver.quit();
            //Kill les process
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: search above how to switch to frame.

Comment: @GaurangShah I found 2 iFrames on the site + the top window, tried the 3 and still not working

Answer (score 0):

It might be dinamically loaded on the page, try to use WebdriverWait. And please pay attention on xpath, I've changed it a little. Checked execution in IE

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

driver.get("http://arender.fr/ARender/");

//Click element after it bacomes clickable
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[div[@title='Next page']]"))).click();
```

Comment: As already said before, even with a pause of 30s between 
`driver.get("http://arender.fr/ARender/");`
 and the click still does not work,
I tried with your elementToBeClickable, return that it never finds it

`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //td[div[@title='Next page']] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)`

I tried it as a normal click and as  I expected, it don't work...

Comment: Does it clicks anywhere else in IE for you? Looks like it might be because of settings.

Answer (score -1):

Seems the ID which you used in you xpath is dynamically generated. (@id='id_#_0.7290579307692522') can you confirm it's remains same even after refreshing the page?

If not try to make xpath with some other attributes or use xpath whilecard search.

[Xpath wildcard search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287556/xpath-wildcard-search)

thanks

Comment: Even with the source which is not generated it does the same thing, i used FireBug only to be sure that my syntax wasn't the problem and it still find anything...
and actually, with many xpath, selenium IDE (Yes my problem is on WebDriver Java but I use it sometimeto be sure that the xpath is okay) finds it... with attribute like "//div[@title='Next page']/img" it shows me the right element but he don't want to click it ...

Answer (score -1):

The following XPath should work:

```
//div[@title='Next page']/img
```

Comment: Even with this one it does not work for an unknown reason..
here the Failure trace :

"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //div[@title='Next page']/img"

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` often occurs when the element is not _yet_ loaded. Please add your C# code in your question. Because the XPath is working on my machine.

Comment: That's what I say, the XPath does exists but Selenium can't click it. To be sure that the element was fully loaded I tried with a THIRTY SECONDS pause, still do the "NoSuchElementException"
I'm on Java and use this to make the click :
 ` driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Next page']/img")).click();`

Comment: @GaurangShah So why does it not work on any frames as said before ?

Comment: As already said before :
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Next page']/img")).click();`
To click, if you want more ask but i dont know what you want and i'm pretty sure that you don't care about the @BeforeTest etc

Comment: @Akiro please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order for us to help you...

Comment: @HappyBird Should be okay now, I guess

Comment: @Akiro, okay good. Now I can see that you're using the InternetExplorerDriver. This can be the cause of the problem. I am using ChromeDriver and it works.

Comment: @HappyBird the test have to be done on IE because I do a test for a web App and the target is to be deployed on IE (don't ask why, my company does stranges things...), Am I blocked ?

Comment: @Akiro, I don't have much experience with the InternetExplorerDriver. This driver can easily cause more trouble than ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver ... Good luck.

Comment: @HappyBird I don't have the choice, any workaround... ?

Comment: @Akiro, I don't know a solution with InternetExplorerDriver... Good luck.